# Using CSS font in canvas not working with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, canvas

I'm making an application in Angular 2 that must generate an image using some parameters setted by the user. I thinked a good idea for do this can be canvas (canvas allow saving generated image, and I need do it for share in social networks).

This parameters must be filled in the image with a custom font (I've .otf files).

I created a Angular 2 component that show the image in a canvas with component attributes like this

```
<app-card [cardStyle]="0" [PAC]="91"></app-card>
```

The CSS of my component contains this code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DINProCond';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/DINPro-Cond.otf') format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'DINProCondBold';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/DINPro-CondBold.otf') format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'DINProBold';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/DINPro-Bold.otf') format("opentype");
}
```

and the component class:

```
//Class header and other properties
  private canvasContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  @ViewChild("canvas") canvas: ElementRef;

  @Input() cardStyle: number;
  @Input() general: number;
  @Input() position: string;
  @Input() PAC: number;
  @Input() SHO: number;
  @Input() PAS: number;
  @Input() DRI: number;
  @Input() DEF: number;
  @Input() PHY: number;

  constructor() {}

  /**
   * This method is called when component is initialized.
   */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.canvasContext = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    let self: CardComponent = this;

    let context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.canvasContext;
    let cardImage: HTMLImageElement = new Image();
    cardImage.onload = function () {
      context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      context.font = self.getFont(self.ZONE_GENERAL);
      self.fillTextInCanvas("PAC", 150, 700, self.getFont(self.ZONE_GENERAL), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL));
      self.fillTextInCanvas(self.PAC.toString(), 50, 700, self.getFont(self.ZONE_GENERAL_VALUES), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL));
      self.fillTextInCanvas("SHO", 150, 790, self.getFont(self.ZONE_GENERAL), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL));
      self.fillTextInCanvas(self.SHO.toString(), 50, 790, self.getFont(self.ZONE_GENERAL_VALUES), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL));
      self.fillTextInCanvas("PAS", 150, 870, self.getFont(self.ZONE_GENERAL), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL));
      self.fillTextInCanvas(self.PAS.toString(), 50, 870, self.getFont(self.ZONE_GENERAL_VALUES), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL));
      self.fillTextInCanvas("DRI", 480, 700, self.getFont(self.ZONE_GENERAL), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL));
      self.fillTextInCanvas(self.DRI.toString(), 380, 700, self.getFont("w"), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL_VALUES));
      self.fillTextInCanvas("DEF", 480, 790, self.getFont(self.ZONE_GENERAL), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL));
      self.fillTextInCanvas(self.DEF.toString(), 380, 790, self.getFont("w"), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL_VALUES));
      self.fillTextInCanvas("PHY", 480, 870, self.getFont(self.ZONE_GENERAL), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL));
      self.fillTextInCanvas(self.PHY.toString(), 380, 870, self.getFont("w"), self.getFontColor(self.ZONE_GENERAL_VALUES));
    };
    cardImage.src = "assets/cards/" + this.cardStyle + ".png";
  }

  /**
   * Get color of font depending of card type selected.
   *
   * @returns {string}
   */
  private getFontColor(zone: string): string {
    return "red"; //TODO
  }

  /**
   * Fill text in canvas
   *
   * @param {string} text
   * @param {number} x
   * @param {number} y
   * @param {string} font
   * @param {string} color
   * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} context
   */
  private fillTextInCanvas(text: string, x: number, y: number, font: string, color: string) {
    this.canvasContext.font = font;
    this.canvasContext.fillStyle = color;
    this.canvasContext.save();
    this.canvasContext.fillText(text, x, y);
    this.canvasContext.restore();
  }
```

When the `ngOnInit` call `fillTextInCanvas()`, I checked with debugger, `font` value is `"48pt DINProCond"` and setted `this.canvasContext.font` is `"64px DINProCond"` (Maybe computed size to px?)

My problem is the text filled in canvas is "painted" without the selected font (the color is OK, but the font is the browser default). I tried load the font in the global CSS and in the component CSS, but without any result.

Maybe painted text before the font can be loaded? Any wrong in my code? Any idea? Thanks you!!

Comment: Usually the loading of your page is triggered before the fonts are loaded (you need to watch for the window loaded event), and that results in the font defaulting even if it is available later. I'm not familiar with angular, but that's an issue I have seen before in rendering fonts in canvas.

Comment: I think I'm painting the text in canvas before the font is loaded, but I'm not sure, and if it the case, how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to delay execution of your code until `window.load`, which is triggered when all related resources are also fetched and ready. There is a way to load in fonts specifically but its wasn't well supported to I don't really have an answer for it.

Comment: Setting the canvas context's `font` property alone won't trigger the downloading of the font. You have to set this font on a visible element through CSS (you can set it on the canvas element, or on an element that you'll temobe later, this should trigger it)

Comment: Thanks you, Kaiido, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by Kaiido solved the problem. I was trying fill text in canvas, but the font is not downloaded.

Setting the font to canvas content don't download the font, I need first some element in DOM that use the font via CSS.

I solved it putting in my HTML a `<span id="load-fonts">Text</span>` and indicate via CSS this span use the font.

**Note**: The element must be contains some text.

```
#load-font {
    font-family: "DinProCond";
}
```